# What is a batch process in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am looking though some tests about T-SQL querying for SQL Server 2012, and encountered one which asked which object should be used when developing a batch process to return a result set based, based on parameters, which can perform a join with a table.

One of the *incorrect* answers to this question was an "inline user-defined function". This surprised me, as it would seem to meet the requirements - therefore, I assume I must be misunderstanding what is meant by "batch process".

So, what does batch process mean in the context of SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Seems a badly written question to me. Option C could be either an inline or multi statement TVF. It doesn't specify. But then again the only types of function that can be inline are table valued ones so A implies a type of TVF. And nothing in the question indicates that only a multi statement one will do to me.

Comment: I think inline user-defined function was thrown in there as a curveball, what the author should have stated explicitly is that they meant an inline scalar function (which doesn't exist). A may as well say "gremlins" but it is ambiguous enough to fool people into believing they meant table-valued...

Comment: @AaronBertrand though given that the BOL topic on inline TVFs calls them [inline user-defined functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx) that is a pretty poor omission.

Comment: @Martin oh, that is terrible... all around.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am actually using `VCE` tests that are part of `70-461 Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012` exam preparation. I am not sure how these tests are created - I guess the man who have created the test did not remember exactly the question or something and doubt such question will be included in real exam.